# How could I do a login form with a login - function to start as i hit the submit button in php?

Tags: php, forms, authentication

I am trying to use Javascript only when necessary.
I am not even sure if my function works (i hope so). All that i really know is that, when i hit the submit button, nothing happens.
I think that my main problem is that my submit button misses something, but I don't know what and most results in google give me different methods and i feel confused.
I would like that, when i hit that button, a function in another class would start and that it would redirect me into another page.

This is what I have done until now.

Login.php

```
<h1>Login</h1>

    <?php
    $utente = new Utente();

    $form = new Form('login', 'login.php', 'POST', '$utente->Login()');
    $form->open();
    $form->addInput('text', 'utente', 1, 'utente');
    $form->addInput('password', 'password', 1, 'password');
    $form->addInput('submit', 'submit', 0, 0, 0, 'login');
    $form->close();


    ?>
</div>
```

Class Form.php

```
 public $name;
 public $action;
 public $method;
 public $onsubmit; 

function __construct($name, $action, $method, $onsubmit) {
    $this->name = $name;
    $this->action = $action;
    $this->method = $method;
    $this->onsubmit = $onsubmit;
}


function open($args = null) {
    echo '<table>'
    . '<form name ="' . $this->name . '" action="' . $this->action . '" method="' . $this->method . '" onsubmit="' . $this->onsubmit . '" ' . $args . '>';
}

function close() {
    echo '</form>'
    . '</table>';
}
function addInput($type, $name, $required = null, $label = null, $placeholder = null, $args = null) {
    if ($label != null) {
        echo '<tr><td><label>' . ucfirst($label) . ': </td>';
    }
    echo '<td><input type="' . $type . '" name="' . $name . '" id="' . $name . '"';
    if ($required != null) {
        echo ' required ';
    }
    if ($placeholder != null) {
        echo 'placeholder="' . $placeholder . '"';
    }
    echo ' ' . $args . ' ></td>';
    if ($label != null) {
        echo '</label>';
    }
    echo '</tr>';
}
```

Class Utente.php (Login() is the function i would like to start, I would make it that it redirects me into another page if everything is right.

```
public function Login() {


    $utente = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'utente', FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS);
    $password = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'password', FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS);

    if (!$this->CheckLoginInDB($utente, $password)) {
        return false;
    }

    session_start();

    window.location.replace("index.php");
    return true;
}

public function CheckLoginInDB($utente, $password) {
    $db = new Db();
    $query = "Select CODICE, UTENTE, PASSWORD from utenti" .
            " where utente=:utente and password=:password ";
    $statement = $db->prepare($query);
    $statement->bindValue(':utente', $utente, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $statement->bindValue(':password', $password, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $statement->execute();
    if (PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_FOUND_ROWS > 0) {
            $uData = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
            $this->setCodice($uData->CODICE);
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You're using JavaScript inside php

Comment: window.location.replace("index.php");

Comment: So instead of that line you have to use header() function and add the Location redirection to it

Comment: So instead of 
window.location.replace("index.php");

I should use
header('Location: index.php');?

Comment: exactly! just that try it

Comment: I suppose that when you click submit your request is being submitted to the right controller

Comment: It still doesn't work, but at least I guess that a problem is resolved. Probably something with my password encryption.

Comment: the point is that you don't catch the submitted request

Comment: In your Login.php you just create the form

Comment: $form = new Form('login', 'login.php', 'POST', '$utente->Login()'); I think you want to attach a callback here, but it actually seems that you are passing a string

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by that? I must get used with forms.

Comment: You have to catch the request you make to the server by using $_POST

Comment: Shouldn't that be managed by "$utente = filter_input(...)?

Comment: Yes but filter input has to be called in the right context, if the $_POST array is empty it won't do anything